# Update Parent record fields using force recordData

Tags: lightning

Is there a way i can update parent record details while using the recordData on child component. For example, I want to update account field (Number of Employees) from a component on contact record page which is using recordData.

Comment: Even if thats possible won't it open up the system to incorrect values if data was created/deleted/edited from classic, API or batch job?

Comment: The example may not make much sense. I just wanted to know if that is possible and if that is not possible via recordData, what would the best way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're limiting yourself to just using recordData then the answer is "no".

However, using recordData you can pull the parentId to pass to an apex method that can then update the account field you'd like on the update of the child record with recordData.